# Should I worry about losing 10liter water/day? (2.5gallon)

Tags: plumbing, leak

After using 100m^3 extra water last year, I installed a Raspberry Pi with a camera to look at my water meter. Soon it will be able to cut off the water on excessive drain (like a forgotten garden hose).
I have stopped the toilets leaking, and now I'm down to losing about ½liter per hour.
It is on the hot water (shower) circuit, If I close the hot water, no drain.[image]
Each little blip on the graph is 1/8 turn of the 1l dial on the meter, i.e. 0.125l.
[image: Hot water turned off at 11:20]
Here the hot water is turned off at 11:20

It must be under the floor.
In the bathroom (but the plumbing is in the wall) and the boilerroom, the floor is tiles on top of concrete, then some isolation.
In the kithen I believe is (from bottom) earth, concrete, insulation, chipboard, floorboards, but the pipes just comes in from the boilerroom, then up to the sink.

It can't be upstairs; a bucket of water would be noticed.
If I just monitor the loss, and it does not get worse, is it worth going through the concrete to find this small leak?

[*] For non-metric, each blip is 1/4 pint, 1/2 cup, and the loss is about 2½ gallon per day.
[image]

The software is an adaption of https://blog.m.nu/vattenmatning-med-raspberry-pi-och-webkamera/ in Swedish, I'm afraid.

I could put it on github I guess...

There is a gap between the pressure valve outlet and the drain, but I have left a cup there for 15 minutes, and it is completely dry.

Comment: Are you sure your pipes are actually buried in the concrete? Seems strange that they're on the outside of the thermal envelope of the house (below insulation), but then I'm not that familiar with on-slab construction (and this sounds like an older non-North American construction, since you mentioned both chipboard and floorboards).

Comment: I'd also try to further isolate the leak before tearing up concrete. Turn off shut-off valves to fixtures, and install them if you don't have them. It's possible there's a leak in a wall or something too. You should also check the T&P valve on your hot water tank, those do leak sometimes and usually setup so if they open the water goes down a drain, that might go unnoticed. There should be an air gap, so you could put a bucket or something underneath to see if anything is coming out.

Comment: I agree with @gregmac in that the leak isn't necessarily under the floor. Spend a bit more time isolating where it is

Comment: At least in the bathroom and boilerroom it is tiles on top of concrete. Only in the kitchen is with wooden floors, and the outlet is just 10 cm in from the  boiler room. 
Fixtures are not leaking.

Comment: I agree with @gregmac it may not be a leak at all but the pressure fluctuations from the hot water system pushing some water back through the meter then with cooling water flows in with no real ussage. I have seen this in the past on systems with no check valve you get charged for water going both ways on the meters in my area and no real water was used.  A check valve and expansion tank can eliminate this problem.

Comment: No, the water is not flowing out; I have the meter on camera ;-)

Comment: @Lenne but you don't know how your meter reacts to water going 'backwards' through it.

Comment: @EdBeal, I had the plumber pressure the hot water circuit today, and at 7 bar, almost double normal pressure, there were no leak.
When releasing the pressure back into the supply, the meter could run backwards.
But we noticed the pressure could vary between 3.5 and 4 bar, and the meter went forwards while the pressure increased, but not when it decreased. Perhaps the meter is more sensitive for inflow than outflow?

As a pressure meter with m-bus cost more than the water I "lose"; seeing the correlation between usage and pressure will not be monitored; even though it would be fun...

Comment: The hotwater tank must expand under the higher pressure; the cold water circuit can not expand (much).

Comment: Water meters or the water meters I have worked on cannot detect the direction of the flow there is a vane that flops back and forth that triggers the meter to move. I have seen this on larger systems and the only way to stop it was installing a check valve and small expansion tank to keep the over pressure valve from leaking when the water is heated with no usage the system over pressures and causes the relief valve to leak. Google this and I am sure you will find similar events. You turned the water supply off what about just turning the power off to the boiler and monitoring with water on.

Comment: Turned off heater, No difference.